# checking if the string is anagram

Tags: c, segmentation-fault, anagram

What is possibly wrong with this code?
I think error is in the first for loop where I am trying to typecast char to int. Is there any other approach that can be applied to check whether the string is anagram?

```
# include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
# define NO_OF_CHARS 256

void areAnagram(char *str1, char *str2)
{

    int count1[NO_OF_CHARS] = {0};
    int count2[NO_OF_CHARS] = {0};
    int i;


    for (i = 0; str1[i] && str2[i]; i++)
    {
        int a = str1[i] - '0';
        int b = str2[i] - '0'; 
        count1[a]++;
        count2[b]++;
    }


    if (str1[i] || str2[i])
    printf("No");


    for (i = 0; i < NO_OF_CHARS; i++)
        if (count1[i] != count2[i])
            printf("No");

    printf("Yes");
}


int main(void)
{
    char *str1;
    char *str2;
    scanf("%s", str1);
    scanf("%s", str2);
    areAnagram(str1, str2);
    return 0;
}
```

> Gives segmentation fault error at runtime.

PS - A string str1 is a anagram of str2 if all the characters in str1 appear the same number of times in str2 and str2 is of the same length as str1

Comment: Why would you subtract `'0'` from the characters? You end up with negative indices, thus indexing out-of-bounds.

Comment: Why do you need `- '0'`?

Comment: to typecast the char value to int.

Comment: That is not a cast. You just subtract one integer from another.

Comment: `count1[string[i]]++;` wasnt working so I thought to explicitly typecast and then increment.

Comment: Use `UCHAR_MAX` for the arrays. And note that the signed-ness of `char` is implementation defined. Negative indexes result in out-of-bounds accessing the arrays, which is **undefined behaviour**.

Comment: Removed the subtraction part and used `count1[string[i]]++;`  instead. And solution provided by @Rabid76 worked.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You never allocated any memory for `char *str1;` and `char *str2;`. Adapt your code like this:

```
#define MAX_STR_LEN 100

int main(void)
{
    char str1[ MAX_STR_LEN ];
    char str2[ MAX_STR_LEN ];
    scanf("%s", str1);
    scanf("%s", str2);
    areAnagram(str1, str2);
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: NO_OF_CHARS is the number of characters in the (presumed) charset, not the maximum length any string. Your first version was perfectly OK.

Answer (score 0):

You need only one count array, `count`. Then increment `count` array element by str1 (`count[str1[i]]++;`) and decrement `count` array element by str2 (`count[str2[i]]--;`). If all elements of `count` are zero then it is anagram.

Answer (score 0):

```
#include<stdio.h>
#include<conio.h>
void main()
{
    char s[30],s1[30];
    int i,j,count=0,count1=0;
    clrscr();
    printf("enter 2 strings\n");
    gets(s);
    printf("\n");
    gets(s1);
    for(i=0,j=0;s[i]!='\0',s1[j]!='\0';i++,j++)
    {
        count=count+(int)s[i];
        count1=count1+(int)s1[j];
    }
    s[i]='\0';
    printf("\n%d",count);
    printf("\n%d",count1);
    if(count==count1)
    printf(" \n\n string is anagram ");
    else
    printf(" \n\n string is not anagram ");
    getch();

}
```

Comment: Could you please [edit] in an explanation of why this code answers the question? Code-only answers are [discouraged](http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/148272/274165), because they don't teach the solution.